# How to enable hardware virtualization on a MacBook?

Tags: windows, bios, virtualization, macbook, boot-camp

I need to enable hardware virtualization on my MacBook Air 2013. I want to run the Windows Phone 8 emulator, which requires hardware virtualization. I am running Windows 8 in boot camp. On my old PC, I enabled it through the BIOS, but this option won't work for a MacBook.

The MacBook Air 2013 has a i5-4250U processor, which is on [Intel's list of Virtualization Technology supported processors](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology).

How would this be done?

In the performance tab of Task Manager, Virtualization appears to be disabled.[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After hours of searching the internet, I discovered how to enable virtualization in Boot Camp.  Instead of booting into Windows by holding the `option` key on startup, boot in to OS X. Then go to System Preferences -> Startup Disk and choose your Boot Camp partition. The computer will restart and boot into Windows, with virtualization enabled.

Comment: Weird how that would make a difference...

Comment: lol this actually worked. I have no idea how.. but it worked.

Comment: Is there any possible to enable BIOS virtualization setting without restart system.Or possible to change inside the system .My system while restarting F2 button is not working i need to enable BIOS virtualization.Is there any possible?

Comment: It works because OSX enables Virtulisation by default.  The Bootcamp Drivers do not.  Hence, by going into OSX first then rebooting into Windows it works.  When rebooting into Windows from OSX it's not a cold boot, therefore the virtualisation settings are still enabled from booting into OSX.

Comment: Looks like the latest update to OSX has resolved it. I finally can install Windows10. For the record, I'm running Win10 Anniversary edition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me

Comment: It doesn't work. Virtualization is always disabled. Late 2013 iMac 27in

Comment: This is still broken in 2022. Running 2015 MacBook Air latest Windows 10 and latest BootCamp. One solution is to boot to Linux or OSX first then reboot to Windows. A better solution is to use an EFI bootmanager that can set the CPU VMX bit. rEFInd is what I'm currently using (use `enable_and_lock_vmx` as explained in the rEFInd config). BootCamp would be the proper place to put this but Apple seems to have no interest.