# Ubuntu on VMWare Fusion keep showing black screen on load - macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-fusion, xubuntu

I'm trying to install latest **Xubuntu** on my VmWare Fusion on macOS Catalina.

I downloaded the `xubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`

I installed it, everything seems fine the way to the end.

But when I try to load it, I see black screen.

[image]

This is my current settings

[image]

[image]

What else should I check ?

Comment: Unless you specifically request otherwise, the version you downloaded will be 64-bit.  Do you have hardware virtualization enabled on your MAC?  You would need to start in BIOS to check.

Comment: I think it is 64 bits, How do I check if I havve "hardware virtualization enabled on my MAC" ?

Comment: You would need to start your MAC in BIOS or Firmware, or see if there is a BIOS display / reading app

Comment: Check this SE link below for checking Hardware Virtualization:  https://superuser.com/questions/717421/how-to-enable-hardware-virtualization-on-a-macbook

Comment: Did you check whether you can run 64-bit guests?

Comment: What version of Fusion? 11.5 is needed for Catalina